# What unit (px, dip, ?) is expected for the ints in AlertDialog.html#setView(View, int, int, int, int)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Can anyone tell me which unit (pixels, dp's, something else?) is expected for the left/top/right/bottom spacing `int`s passed to `AlertDialog.html#setView(View, int, int, int, int)`?

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) doesn't say, no suprise there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in pixel. I think that everytime you programatically set a dimension in Android it will be in pixel.

if you want to be pixel independant you can use a dimension defined in you xml:

```
int valueInPixels = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.yourdimension)
```

or programatically:

```
Resources r = getResources();
float valueInPixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
```